Highcharts.js - in bullet chart, make the target line dashed
In Highcharts, I want to create a bullet chart.
But I want the target line to be dashed.
I don't see such an option in the target API.
Link to target API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bullet.targetOptions
Is there are some workarounds to achieve that?
Example of bullet chart for docs:
https://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/


Highcharts.setOptions({
    chart: {
        type: 'bullet'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            pointPadding: 0.25,
            borderWidth: 0,
            color: '#000',
            targetOptions: {
                width: '200%'
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
});

Highcharts.chart('container', {
    series: [{
        data: [{
            y: 275,
            target: 250
        }]
    }]
});
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/bullet.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
</figure>



And I want the target line to be dashed.
This is how I want it to look like:

Thanks in advance

The target graphic is a rect SVG element, so it's not possible to set dashstyle attribute on it. As a solution, you can render an additional path element which will partially cover the default target.
For example:
(function(H) {
  H.wrap(H.Series.types.bullet.prototype, 'drawPoints', function(proceed) {
    const chart = this.chart;
    proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

    this.points.forEach(point => {
      const target = point.targetGraphic;
      const bbox = target.getBBox();

      chart.renderer.path([
          'M', bbox.x, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2,
          'L', bbox.x + bbox.width, bbox.y + bbox.height / 2
        ])
        .attr({
          'stroke-width': 3,
          stroke: '#000',
          dashstyle: 'dash'
        })
        .add(target.parentGroup)
    });
  });
}(Highcharts));


Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/d2hqr1jn/
API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#path
Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts
